# How can I use Siri without saying "Hey Siri"?

Tags: siri

I have never used Siri; all that I have read says to activate it by saying "Hey Siri".

This may be acceptable in American culture but I regard it as rude and vulgar.
From childhood I have been taught NEVER to say "Hey" and cannot imaging saying "Hey Siri".

In what other ways can I use Siri without having to say "Hey Siri"?

Answer (score 2):

There is a Siri button right next to the search icon on the top right corner of your screen.

Answer (score 1):

Saying "Hey Siri" is only one of the options for using the feature.

- To view all of the Siri options on iOS, go to **Settings > Siri & Search**
- To view all of the Siri options on macOS, go to **Apple > System Preferences > Siri**

From either of the above you can enable or disable the *Listen for "Hey Siri"* option (note that not all Mac models will offer this specific option).

However, by accessing Settings or System Preferences you will find other options for engaging with Siri (e.g. using the Home button on an iPhone, holding the <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>space</kbd> keys down on a Mac, etc).

Comment: Also, on iOS in Settings > Accessibility > Siri, you can enable "Type to Siri" to have a text-only interaction by pressing the side/lock button. When enabled, this still allows verbal invocation and feedback via Hey Siri.